# Onclick only works on second click. How to get it to work on first click

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get onclick to work on first click?  I have multiple instances on the same page. Here is my code:

```
<script>
function showMoreOrLess(thisObj) {
  var caption = thisObj.innerHTML;
  var otherObj = thisObj.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
  if (caption == "Read more") {
    otherObj.style.display = "inline";
    thisObj.innerHTML = "Read less";
  } else {
    otherObj.style.display = "none";
    thisObj.innerHTML = "Read more";
  } 
} 
</script>
<p><a onclick="showMoreOrLess(this);">Read more </a></p>
```

Comment: As an aside, this is a great opportunity to start using your browser's debugging tools.  Stepping through this in a debugger you would observe that `onclick` *does* in fact work and you'd be able to directly observe how your code is behaving and why.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space

```
<a onclick="showMoreOrLess(this);">Read more </a>
```

to

```
<a onclick="showMoreOrLess(this);">Read more</a>
```

Comment: Because `'Read more '` is not the same as `'Read more'` when comparing against `'Read more'`

Comment: That actually worked for making it work on first click.  Thank you.  Do you know if there is a way to add a string into the Read more, so that the GTM can fire on the name?  (these are interviews of different people)                                        <%# IfEmpty(Eval("Name"), "", "<span class='Name'>" + Eval<string>("Name") + "</span>") %>